# LinkedIn Ads Analytics API does not return certain metrics namely 'sends' and 'viralCommentLikes'

Tags: api, analytics, linkedin-api, reporting, ads

I am using LinkedIn Ad Analytics API to get the report stats from LinkedIn. However we are missing few fields namely 'sends' and 'viralCommentLikes' in the response.

Sample Request:

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adAnalyticsV2?q=analytics&pivot=CREATIVE&dateRange.start.day=18&dateRange.start.month=10&dateRange.start.year=2018&timeGranularity=DAILY&accounts=urn:li:sponsoredAccount:123456789&dateRange.end.day=18&dateRange.end.month=10&dateRange.end.year=2018

I found out that this is because of the permission issues. Access token do not have permission to get values for sends.

Does anyone have knowledge regarding the required LinkedIn App permissions to get values for 'sends' and 'viralCommentLikes' metrics or where we can ask it from LinkedIn support?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems that these metrics are now available (as of September 2019):

"Four new metrics are available: reactions, viralReactions, sends, and viralCommentLikes."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/recent-changes#september-2019

Please refer to the [Metrics Available in the API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads-reporting/ads-reporting#metrics-available) for field descriptions.